# How do I pass gson JsonObject between fragments in the same activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, gson

I'm refactoring my app and currently rewriting two activities as two fragments in the same activity. This was how I used to send gson JsonObject from the first activity to the second activity:

Activity1:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
intent.putExtra("form", gson.toJson(form));
startActivity(intent);
```

Activity2:

```
intent = getIntent();
form = gson.fromJson(intent.getStringExtra("form"), JsonObject.class);
```

Now that I've rewritten `Activity1` and `Activity2` as fragments in the same activity, is there a similar approach that I can use to send and retrieve data in the fragments? I just find using intents very intuitive, but I figured fragments use a different way of communicating with one another.

Comment: do you want to pass data between activity -> fragment or fragment -> fragment ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("form", gson.toJson(form));
secondFragment.setArguments(args);
```

and in your targeted Fragment :

```
getArguments().getString("form");
```

Comment: Does this statement  `getArguments().getString("form")` automatically retrieve a gson object?

Comment: No, you have to use Gson class to convert it to the object

Answer (score 1):

Hi hope i am not late on this. Using the [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) Library you can achieve this feature.

In your first fragment say Fragment A. you can parse the Gson to a new

```
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
 bundle.putSerializable("form", new Gson().toJson(Form));
 FragmentA fragment = new FragmentA();
 fragment.setArguments(bundle);
 loadFragment(fragment); // TODO
```

Then get this in your second fragment (Fragment B) as so

```
private Form form;

....
....

Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
  if(bundle != null){
      form = new Gson().fromJson((String) bundle.getSerializable("form"), Form.class);
      // get parameters e.g form name, form id
      String name = form.getName();
      ....
            }
```

Hope this helps. Have fun :)